# Not getting topic in /tabletop_segmentation_markers

Tags: rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Im trying to get the segmentation part of the tabletop_object_detector stack to work.  To do this I launched the tabletop_segmentation.launch and changed the params in it as seen in this question
http://answers.ros.org/question/63378/tabletop_segmentation-in-rviz/
But the difference is that my Kinect does not give a /camera/depth_registered/points topic but a /camera/depth/points, both being a message type pointcloud2
But when I either rostopic echo tabletop_segmentation_markers or try to see it in rviz with segmentationObject I get either no response or a empty topic.

right now im working with a kinect in fuerte and to obtain the point cloud i used the openni camera deprecated stack, I would really appreciate any help.

My tabletop_segmentation.launch is:

```
<arg name="tabletop_segmentation_points_in" default="/camera/depth_registered/points" />
<arg name="tabletop_segmentation_convert_to_base_link" default="false" />
<arg name="tabletop_segmentation_clustering_voxel_size" default="0.003" />
<arg name="flatten_table" default="false"/>
<arg name="table_padding" default="0.02"/>

<node pkg="tabletop_object_detector" name="tabletop_segmentation" type="tabletop_segmentation" respawn="true" output="screen">
<!--topic remapping-->
    <remap from="cloud_in" to="$(arg tabletop_segmentation_points_in)" />
    <remap from="segmentation_srv" to="tabletop_segmentation" />
    <remap from="markers_out" to="tabletop_segmentation_markers" />

<param name="clustering_voxel_size" value="$(arg tabletop_segmentation_clustering_voxel_size)" />
<param name="inlier_threshold" value="300" />
<param name="plane_detection_voxel_size" value="0.01" />
<param name="cluster_distance" value="0.03" />
<param name="min_cluster_size" value="300" />
<param name="flatten_table" value="$(arg flatten_table)" />
<param name="table_padding" value="$(arg table_padding)" />

<!-- processing and filtering frame -->
<!-- all clouds converted to and processed in base link frame -->
<param if="$(arg tabletop_segmentation_convert_to_base_link)" name="processing_frame" value="base_link" />
<param if="$(arg tabletop_segmentation_convert_to_base_link)" name="up_direction" value="1.0" />
<param if="$(arg tabletop_segmentation_convert_to_base_link)" name="z_filter_min" value="0.35" />
<param if="$(arg tabletop_segmentation_convert_to_base_link)" name="z_filter_max" value="1.0" />
<param if="$(arg tabletop_segmentation_convert_to_base_link)" name="y_filter_min" value="-1.2" />
<param if="$(arg tabletop_segmentation_convert_to_base_link)" name="y_filter_max" value="1.2" />
<param if="$(arg tabletop_segmentation_convert_to_base_link)" name="x_filter_min" value="0.3" />
<param if="$(arg tabletop_segmentation_convert_to_base_link)" name="x_filter_max" value="1.0" />
<param if="$(arg tabletop_segmentation_convert_to_base_link)" name="table_z_filter_min" value="-0.5" />
<param if="$(arg tabletop_segmentation_convert_to_base_link)" name="table_z_filter_max" value="-0.01" />        

<!-- all clouds will be processed in the incoming frame, which is -->
<!-- assumed to the the camera's optical frame -->
<param unless="$(arg tabletop_segmentation_convert_to_base_link)" name="processing_frame" value="" />
<param unless="$(arg tabletop_segmentation_convert_to_base_link)" name="up_direction" value="-1.0" />
<param unless="$(arg tabletop_segmentation_convert_to_base_link)" name="z_filter_min" value="0.4" />
<param unless="$(arg tabletop_segmentation_convert_to_base_link)" name="z_filter_max" value="1.25" />
<param unless="$(arg tabletop_segmentation_convert_to_base_link)" name="y_filter_min" value="-1.2" />
<param unless="$(arg tabletop_segmentation_convert_to_base_link)" name="y_filter_max" value="1.2" />
<param unless="$(arg tabletop_segmentation_convert_to_base_link)" name="x_filter_min" value="-1.2" />
<param unless="$(arg tabletop_segmentation_convert_to_base_link)" name="x_filter_max" value="1.2" />
<param unless="$(arg tabletop_segmentation_convert_to_base_link)" name="table_z_filter_min" value="0.01" />
<param unless="$(arg tabletop_segmentation_convert_to_base_link)" name="table_z_filter_max" value="0.5" />          

</node>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/78081/not-getting-topic-in-/tabletop_segmentation_markers/) by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2013-09-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [openni_launch wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch#Quick_start) describes how to enable depth registration using dynamic_reconfigure.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2013-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-09-12**:
Thanks, but the rqt_reconfigure stack is not available for fuerte, so can i use the groovy one in fuerte? Also even though I dont have the /camera/depth_registered/points , the tabletop_segmentation should work if i have the /camera/depth/points because both are PointCloud2? Or am I missing something?

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-09-12**:
Right now I can see the /camera/depth_registered/points , but the weird thing is that when i
roslaunch tabletop_object_detector tabletop_segmentation.launch
the kinect does not "turn on" i dont see the laser coming out of it, but when i do
rostopic echo /camera/depth_registered/points the kinect "turns on" and i can see the topic, so i think i have a problem with the .launch that is not obtaining correctly the topic.  Does this make sense?

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2013-09-12**:
In fuerte, you can use rosrun `dynamic_reconfigure reconfigure_gui`
I don't think I understand what you mean about a laser or the kinect "turning on." Regardless of anything else you're running, the kinect should always be producing data. rostopic hz should help determine if it is.

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-09-12**:
What i mean is that the Kinect gives the data when a node is subscribed to this topic, so what i found was that my launch file is not subscribing correctly to the data given by the kinect, so the segmentation is not working.  Do you know why this is happening?